# Rails finding by params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, postgresql

I'm building a API and want the show page for a user to be found by 'uid' instead of the record ID

I have this in my controller

```
    def show
      respond_with User.find_by_uid(params[:uid])
    end
```

When I go to localhost/api/v1/users/8888888  Its returns "Null"

Finding by ID seems to work fine, am I doing something wrong here?
I tried put this in the rails console and it worked

```
    User.find_by_uid("8888888")
```

I'm new to rails

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried visiting:

`localhost/api/v1/users?uid= 8888888` instead of the url you are using currently, except you are handling that correctly rails would have no knowledge of the `uid param` alternatively you could add this to your `config/routes.rb` file

```
get 'users/:uid', to: 'users#show'
```

With the hope that your `controller` is called `UsersController` then you can call `localhost/api/v1/users/8888888` in your browser and it should behave as expected

Comment: Ah excellent thanks so much, Ill correct answer you in 5 mins :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than just giving you the answer, I'll provide a tip on debugging Ruby applications (including Rails).

Get the pry gem and the pry-debugger gem and include them in your Rails application (there's plenty of posts around Google on how to include pry and pry-debugger in Rails).

put 'binding.pry' (without the quotes) at the beginning of your show method.  In the console where your server runs, when show gets executed, execution will halt/pause at binding.pry. Type the following in the pry console to see what is available in the rails params hash.

pry> params
(this will print out the contents of params)

I would start my troubleshooting here, and post the contents of params and any relevant server logging here if you still can't figure it out.

*edit*
I don't have enough rep to comment, yet.  Only really been on this site and using it a day or two.

Comment: This would have been better off as a comment than an answer, as it is really no answer to the question from the OP